# Can a subscription remain subscribed if returning a still subscribed observable from a switchmap

Tags: rxjs

Consider the following:

```
a$ = someObservable$.pipe(
  switchMap(data => liveForEver$)
);

a$.subscribe();
a$.unsubscribe();
```

Now, liveForEver$ as the name suggests is subscribed to by other parts of the code. Could it be that a$ will stay subscribed after a$ is unsubscribed because switchMap returns a 'living' observable?

Comment: Subscriptions in general are independent, ie they create their own execution of the observable. This isn't true for multicasted observables which produce independent of subscribers, but then share those values among all. When you unsubscribe a$, the specific inner subscription to liveForEver$ will be terminated. That doesn't stop it from producing values or affect any other subscriptions to it, though. It depends on what liveForEver$ is.

Comment: Addendum: "could it be that a$ stays subscribed" —> no, when you unsubscribe a$, a$ will no longer be subscribed, no matter what liveForEver$ is or does.

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought. So, there seems to be another mysterious subscription hanging out there lurking for my observables. poetry is all I got left with now ...

Answer (score 0):

When an operator is defined, it usually has behavior to unsubscribe to child subscriptions when it is unsubscribed to. If you make a custom operator and fail to do this, then you'll likely create memory leaks. Consider the following custom operator:

```
function timesTwo(input$: Observable<number>): Observable<number> {
  return new Observable<number>(observer => {
    input$.subscribe({
      next: val => observer.next(val * 2),
      complete: () => observer.complete(),
      error: err => observer.error()
    });
    return {
      // I should $input.unsubscribe()
      unsubscribe: () => {/*Do Nothing*/}
    }
  });
}

function timesTwoPipeable<T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return input$ => timesTwo(input$);
}
```

Here I've created my own custom rxjs operator that multiplies a stream of inputs by two. So 1:

```
const subscription = interval(1000).pipe(map(x => x * 2))
  .subscribe(console.log);
setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe(), 5000);
```

and 2:

```
const subscription = timesTwo(interval(1000))
  .subscribe(console.log);
setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe(), 5000);
```

and 3:

```
const subscription = interval(1000).pipe(timesTwoPipeable())
  .subscribe(console.log);
setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe(), 5000);
```

All have identical outputs to the console, but 2 and 3 both subscribe to the interval stream and then do not unsubscribe to it. So the second two quietly create a memory leak. You could test this yourself by changing `interval(1000)` to `interval(1000).pipe(tap(_ => console.log("Still Alive")))` in all three examples.

All the built-in RxJS operators clean up after themselves. If you build your own, be sure to do the same!

---

Something I noticed in your question is that you tried to unsubscribe to an observable. I'm surprised that didn't create an error.

My inderstanding is that:

```
a$.subscribe();
a$.unsubscribe();
```

should be:

```
const sub = a$.subscribe();
sub.unsubscribe();
```